# Django admin application works 100% for superuser but for staff users with full permissions some apps don't appear for users

Tags: python, django, django-admin, user-permissions

My Django admin application works 100% for superuser but for staff users with full permissions some apps like GARAGE don't appear for users even though it has full permissions! How can I debug or where can I be blocking this access in my code? I don't use decorator or proxy! I don't use custom template! I don't have has_perm or has_module_perms in my code

Permissions user
[all users permissions actived](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmV54.png)

Admin Site
[Django Admin dont show App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QCfV.png)

```
#settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'garagem.apps.GaragemConfig',    
    'ckeditor',
    'covid',
    'documento',    
    'agenda.apps.AgendaConfig', 
    'mailer',    
    'ouvidoria.apps.OuvidoriaConfig',
    'licitacao.apps.LicitacaoConfig',
    'demanda.apps.DemandaConfig',
    'compras.apps.ComprasConfig',
    'procedimento.apps.ProcedimentoConfig',
    'solicitacao.apps.SolicitacaoConfig',
    'endereco.apps.EnderecoConfig',
    'servidor.apps.ServidorConfig',
    'parametros.apps.ParametrosConfig',
    'comunicacao.apps.ComunicacaoConfig',
    'receita.apps.ReceitaConfig',
    'artigo.apps.ArtigoConfig',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',    
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',    
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',    
    'debug_toolbar',    
    'core',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken'
]
​
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]
​
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 )
​
#urls.py
​
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from . import views
from django.views.generic import TemplateView # <--
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
import debug_toolbar
from rest_framework.schemas import get_schema_view
from rest_framework import routers
from servidor.api import viewsets as servidorsiewset
route = routers.DefaultRouter()
route.register(r'servidorapi', servidorsiewset.ServidorViewSet ,basename='servidorapi')
favicon_view = RedirectView.as_view(url='/static/favicon.ico', permanent=True)
urlpatterns = [
    path('garagem/', include('garagem.urls')),    
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path("login/", views.login, name="login"),
    path('', include('solicitacao.urls')),
    path('cartaoverifica', include('solicitacao.urls')),
    path('cartaoimagem', include('solicitacao.urls')),
    path("logout/", auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name="logout"),
    path('inscricaoevento', include('solicitacao.urls')),    
    path('compras/protocolo/novo', views.protocolo_new, name='protocolo_new'),
    path('solicitacao/', include('solicitacao.urls')),    
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('ouvidoria/', include(('ouvidoria.urls','ouvidoria'),namespace='ouvidoria')),
    path('solicitacao/', include('solicitacao.urls')),
    path('comunicacao/', include('comunicacao.urls')),
    path('receita/', include('receita.urls')),
    path('servidor/', include('servidor.urls')),
    path('procedimento/', include('procedimento.urls')),
    path('compras/', include('compras.urls')),
    path('tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    path('api/', include(route.urls)),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
​
admin.site.site_header = 'Sistema de Gerência de Demandas Internas'
admin.site.site_title = 'Prefeitura Municipal de Taiobeiras - SGDI'
​
​
​
#admin GARAGEM
#admin.py
from servidor.models import Servidor
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from django.contrib import messages
from garagem.models import Veiculo, Retirada
from django.utils.datastructures import MultiValueDictKeyError
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist
from django.templatetags.static import static
from django.utils.html import format_html
​
class VeiculoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    search_fields = ('placa','km')
    list_display = ('placa','modelo', 'km',)
    
​
class RetiradaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:        
        model = Retirada
        fields = '__all__'
        
​
class FilterRetiradaAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,{'fields':[('veiculo','motorista'),('dataretirada','km'),('datadevolucao','km_devolucao'),'filtroDeArcondicionado','freioDeEstacionamento','folgaDoPedalDeEmbreagem','buzina',
        'estintorDeIncendio','paraBrisa','luzes','farois','lanternas','portas','filtroDeArDoMotor','correias','mangueiras','cargaDaBateriaVisor',
        'oleoMotor','fluidoDeFreio','fluidoDeArrefecimento','fluidoDeDirecao','fluidoDoLimpadorDoParabrisa','FluidoDeTransmissao','amortecedores',
        'buchas','coifas','sistemaDeEscape','pneus','pressao','freioDianteiro','freioTraseiro','observacoes']})
    ]
    list_display = ('veiculo_motorista_status','km','km_devolucao','km_rodado_dia','dataretirada','datadevolucao')
    list_filter =('motorista__nome','veiculo__placa','dataretirada')
    form = RetiradaForm
    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # or print debug statements
    # super(save_formset, self).dispatch(request, form, formset, change)
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        """Override the get_form and extend the 'exclude' keyword arg"""
        form = super(FilterRetiradaAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        try:
            id_carro=request.GET['id_carro']                                
            form.base_fields['veiculo'].initial = Veiculo.objects.get(id=id_carro)
            form.base_fields['km'].initial = Veiculo.objects.get(id=id_carro).km
            if not obj and (request.user.is_superuser is False):         
                form.base_fields['motorista'].initial = Servidor.objects.get(user=request.user)
            else:
                try:
                    # import pdb; pdb.set_trace() # or print debug statements
                    # super(save_formset, self).dispatch(request, form, formset, change)
                    ret=Retirada.objects.filter(veiculo=id_carro).first()
                    if ret:
                        form.base_fields['motorista'].initial = Servidor.objects.get(pk=ret.motorista.id)
                except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                      messages.error(request, 'Motorista não localizado')       
        except MultiValueDictKeyError:
            messages.warning(request, 'Favor usar a câmara para ler o codigo de barras')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            messages.error(request, 'Carro não Localizado')      
        return form
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         super(FilterRetiradaAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
         if obj.km_devolucao:
             v=Veiculo.objects.get(id=obj.veiculo.id)
             if v.km < obj.km_devolucao:
                v.km=obj.km_devolucao                
                v.save()
         obj.save()
         messages.warning(request, 'Devolução realizada com Sucesso')
​
    def km_rodado_dia(self, obj):        
        if obj.km_devolucao:
            return (obj.km_devolucao - obj.km)
        else :
            return '-'
    def veiculo_motorista_status(self, obj):        
        # urls = super().get_urls()
        urlsStatic = static('atencao.png')
        if obj.filtroDeArcondicionado != 'OK' or obj.freioDeEstacionamento  != 'OK' or obj.folgaDoPedalDeEmbreagem  != 'OK' or obj.buzina != 'OK' or obj.estintorDeIncendio != 'OK' or obj.paraBrisa != 'OK' or obj.luzes != 'OK' or obj.farois != 'OK' or obj.lanternas != 'OK' or obj.portas != 'OK' or obj.filtroDeArDoMotor != 'OK' or obj.correias != 'OK' or obj.mangueiras != 'OK' or obj.cargaDaBateriaVisor != 'OK' or obj.oleoMotor != 'OK' or obj.fluidoDeFreio != 'OK' or obj.fluidoDeArrefecimento != 'OK' or obj.fluidoDeDirecao != 'OK' or obj.fluidoDoLimpadorDoParabrisa != 'OK' or obj.FluidoDeTransmissao != 'OK' or obj.amortecedores != 'OK' or obj.buchas != 'OK' or obj.coifas != 'OK' or obj.sistemaDeEscape != 'OK' or obj.pneus != 'OK' or obj.pressao != 'OK' or obj.freioDianteiro != 'OK' or obj.freioTraseiro != 'OK':
​
            return format_html('<p>{}/{}<img src="{}" alt="Italian Trulli"></p>',obj.motorista,str(obj.veiculo).upper(),urlsStatic)
        else :
            return format_html('<p>{}/{}</p>',obj.motorista,str(obj.veiculo).upper())
    veiculo_motorista_status.short_description = 'Veiculo / Motorista  '     
​
class RetiradaAdmin(FilterRetiradaAdmin):
​
    autocomplete_fields = ['motorista','veiculo'] #Coloca a pesquisa 
    search_fields = ('motorista__nome','veiculo__placa')
​
admin.site.register(Retirada, RetiradaAdmin)
​
admin.site.register(Veiculo, VeiculoAdmin)
 
 
​
#garagem apps.py
from django.apps import AppConfig
​
​
class GaragemConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'garagem'
```

Answer (score 0):

In Django==3.2.13, creating migrations and migrating them made the app permissions visible in django admin. And I added the permissions to is_staff users. This solved my problem.